# How to access Azure SQL database from Bot framework Composer

Tags: azure-sql-database, bot-framework-composer

I'm trying to access the SQL database from my Bot framework Composer, and I don't seem to find an in-built option for it. Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: can this tutorial: [Saving State data in SQL with .NET](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/26/Saving-State-Sql-Dotnet/) be helpful?

Comment: Thanks @LeonYue, can you help with respect to sending HTTP requests to Azure's SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t believe there is a default action to run SQL commands (only HTTP requests is a built-in external action), but you could use Custom Actions in Bot Framework Composer, in which you can execute your SQL queries:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-add-custom-action

It requires a little programming, but it should do the job.